# constructing a new object and assignment in the same step

Tags: c++

```
const ClassA& curShot = vec_shots[curShotIndx];
```

In the above code the curShot object is constructed and assigned at the same step. My question is which constructor is used in the above statement. I thought it will be the default constructor followed by the assignment operator, but it seems to call the copy constructor instead. Why is that the case?

Comment: That ampersand (`&`) is a typo in your question, isn't it?

Comment: `curShot` is a `const` reference. Analogically you are doing something equivalent to: `const ClassA* const curShot = vec_shots[curShotIndx];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that

```
vec_shots[curShotIndx];
```

returns a reference which you assign to `const ClassA& curShot`. There is no object creation involved in this step. Therefore no constructor is invoked (neither default nor copy constructor).

The assignment operator is not invoked either since you are not assigning one object instance to another, but only a reference. You are not handling more than one (existing) object instance in this code. So, no construction or assignment is invoked.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, just that I had a type above with the &. However, I appreciate your answer because I was not sure what it would do with the & either.

Answer (score 1):

No constructor is used, `curShot` is a reference, an alias to an already existing object, not a stand-alone object by itself.

Also, initialization and assignment cannot be done at the same step. For example, say you had

```
 ClassA original;
 ClassA copy = original;
```

Here, `copy` is not assigned `original`, it's initalized using `original`. This is called copy initialization.

If you did

```
 ClassA copy2(original);
```

this would be called direct initialization.

The copy constructor would be called in both instances. ([copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) can occur, so it might not be called, but it must be available)

Assignment is when you use `operator =` on an already existing object:

```
 ClassA x;
 ClassA y;
 x = y;     //assignment
```

Comment: -1 *The copy constructor would be called in both instances.* Misleading rather wrong.

Comment: @Als in which one is it not called?

Comment: Whether or not the copy constructor will be called during Copy Initilization completely depends on the class definition.If the class provides an appropriate conversion operator which is a better match than the copy constructor then it will be used.

Comment: @Als I don't follow. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Well the copy constructor call can be simply elided. It implies the copy constructor should be present but not necessary that it will be called. For an example, search copy elision and hopefully you should find one.

Comment: @Als You said something about a conversion operator being a better match. [Copy elision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) is a whole different story.

Comment: @Als can you please clarify what you mean by "an appropriate conversion operator which is a better match than the copy constructor"?

Comment: No I do not intend to. I do not have sufficient time.Given that I will remove the downvote. Still *The copy constructor would be called in both instances* is wrong.

Comment: @Als were you referring to a case where there are 2 different classes (note that my first 2 samples, the ones I was referring to, the two objects are of the same type).

Answer (score 1):

Since you wrote "it seems to call copy constructor", **I assume the ampersand in your question is a typo**.
In that case, if you would do

```
const ClassA curShot = vec_shots[curShotIndx];
```

it is evaluated as copy construction. It is just the same as the ugly `const ClassA curShot( vec_shots[curShotIndx] )`.

However, if you write

```
ClassA curShot;  // I skipped the "const", because otherwise the example would be invalid.
curShot = vec_shots[curShotIndx];
```

then a default constructor gets called and an `opearator=` is called on the second line.

---

Moreover, "=" so much can mean calling NEITHER copy constructor NOR `operator=`, that you can have this:

```
const ClassA f(){ return ClassA(); }
//...
const ClassA curShot = f();  // we would expect here a copy constructor call
```

Here -- if the compiler uses return value optimization and usually it does -- only a default constructor gets called for curShot.

Comment: It was indeed a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This statement just define curShot as a reference, it's not a new object.